# How can I make my url patterns to figure out if a given string has a hyphen in it in urls.py Django

Tags: regex, django-urls

I'm trying to make my website to take a string type of url names. Those can be the following: `python`, `python-django`, `python-django-admin`, and so on. I don't know how to check a hyphen in a string in regular expression.
Can anyone help me about his?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Why isn't a simple `string.find('-')` enough? What do you mean by "recognize" strings? Have you tried something first and failed? Do you have an example? This question needs some work before someone can answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work for your examples.

```
^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$
```

Try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/G9ZgTD/1).